# Why is the decimal format not formatting properly?

Tags: java, methods, format

I'm creating a imperial to metric conversion program by creating methods for each conversion. I want to format both the number before and after conversion to two decimal places. As of now, it shows me "100 inches = 254 centimetres". What's going wrong?

```
String strConversionChoice, strValue;
    double  dblInputValue;
    int intConversionChoice;

    strConversionChoice = txtInputConversionChoice.getText();
    strValue = txtInputValue.getText();

    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    intConversionChoice = Integer.parseInt(strConversionChoice);
    dblInputValue = Double.parseDouble(strValue);

    if (intConversionChoice == 1) {
        lblOutput.setText(x.format(dblInputValue) + " inches = " + x.format(inchesToCentimetres(dblInputValue))+ " centimetres");
    }
    else if (intConversionChoice == 2) {
        lblOutput.setText(x.format(dblInputValue) + " feet = " +x.format(feetToCentimetres(dblInputValue)) + " centimetres");
    }
```

Comment: maybe the localization is the cuplprit. did you take it into account?

Comment: If you always want 2 decimal places you need to use `0` instead of `#`. `DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("###.00")`

Comment: @Codebender thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use # in the DecimalFormat class it shows the digits if Non Zero fraction is present else it displays nothing , Make use of 0 instead # if you want to see the digits even if they are 0.

See this **[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)**

Comment: The answer might sometimes have numbers in the decimal places, is there any way to account for both possibilities?

Comment: Using 0 allows you to print the digits as you wish.It will only print 0 if the digit is 0 whereas if you used # the  zero digits will be absent.So as @Codebender said you can use DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("###.00"); to print the correct result.